# how to set dropdown menu a value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table and each row has a checkbox and drop down menu.

This is one row

```
<tr>
   <td><input id="checked1" type="checkbox" class="cd" value="1"></td>
   <td><b>select</b></td>
   <td>
      <select name="questionType" id="questionType" class="qType QSelect">
         <option value="">--Select--</option>
         <option value="1">text</option>
         <option value="2">rate</option>
         <option value="3">etc</option>
         <option class="show-checkboxes" value="4">option</option>
      </select>
   </td>

   <td><input type="hidden" id="optionInputa1"></td>
</tr>
```

I want to set the dropdown to show `text` as selected by using jquery.

here are the 2 ways I tried

```
//$("#checked1").closest("input:select").val('text'); 
$('#checked1').parent().sibling().sibling().children().closest("input:select").val('text');
```

but none works.

Can anyone tell me what is wrong here?

you can see the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/E3q5x/1/)

Comment: do you want to select drop down on check of checkbox and select value should be equal to checkbox value, is that the requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing is super complicated and brittle!

`closest` only traverses upwards, and that selector will never match a `select` because a `select` is not an `input`.

Also you have to set a `select`'s value based on the, er, *value*, not the display text.

And lastly your fiddle doesn't work because there's no table and the `<tr>`s never make it into the DOM.

You want to find the same `select` in that *row*, so just do that:

```
$('#checked1').closest('tr').find('select').val('1');
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/E3q5x/3/

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

**EDIT** : As per discussion on chat, dropdown value get selected on page load and value equal to the checkbox value. Hence jQuery and JSfiddle link updated.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function(){
        $(this).closest('tr').find('select').val( $(this).val());
   });
});
```

Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/E3q5x/13/)

Comment: I want to make the drop down menu to show text when the page is loaded

Comment: call jQuery code inside '$(document).ready(...' as shown in answer

Comment: eevee has already posted and he is the 1st one to answer so I have accepted his/her answer.+1 for your answer

Comment: That's fine. But I would suggest, you should accept the right answer that full fill your requirement and this helps to other who is referring to your questions as many looks for same question asked on SO. No problem... have good day !!

Comment: I dont know why you are linking with the checkbox.When I click on the check box then only the drop down value changes.Even bhaviks answer does the same.But my requirement is to show the drop down value as text as soon as the page loads.May be its my fault ,may be the question is not clear.I apologize for that

Comment: So do you want to set all dropdown values to set to 'text' without selection of checkbox?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55172/discussion-between-jquerylearner-and-bhushan-kawadkar).

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to be done on `checkbox checked` you may try this..

```
$("#checked1").click(function () {
    $("#checked1:checked").parents('tr').find('select').val('1');
});
```

***[`Fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/E3q5x/12/)***